# I can be last or first, what am I?

Tags: riddle

I can go left, I can go right.
You always use me in everyday life.
I am in games, and I can be last or first.
You will use me the most in a hard or soft cover book.

What am I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can go left, I can go right.

> left turn or right turn

You always use me in everyday life.

> U-Turn

I am in games, and I can be last or first.

> Whose turn is it?

You will use me the most in a hard or soft cover book.

> turn the page

What am I?

> turn

Comment: U-Turn: didnt think of it this way originally, but I like that. You nailed it good job.

Answer (score 1):

> "

I can go left, I can go right.

> quotation marks are usually different, tilting to the left or right depending on whether they are at the start or end of a quote.

You always use me in everyday life.

> Quoting things is a part of most peoples everyday lives.

I am in games, and I can be last or first.

> Game dialogue?  Start and end of a sentence.

You will use me the most in a hard or soft cover book.

> Self explanatory?

Comment: Nice try I like this, but not the answer.